# Jetpack Compose Bottom Sheet dim shadow not visible

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I've created a bottom sheet in jetpack compose. But when the bottom sheet is expanding, the bottom sheet outside the background does not dim as usual bottom sheets do. Please help.

```
MyApplicationTestTheme {
    ProvideWindowInsets {
        BottomSheetScaffold(
            scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
            sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 30.dp,topEnd = 30.dp),
            sheetElevation= 5.dp,
            modifier=Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.95f).fillMaxWidth(),
            sheetBackgroundColor=Color.Green,
            sheetContent = {
                //Bottom sheet content
            }, sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp
        ) {
         // Page Content
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you found the solution for it ?

Comment: @AgentP No, I didn't find it. I assume Jetpack's default bottom sheet is different from the previous bottom sheet. Now there aren't any dim outside the bottom sheet.

Answer (score 4):

Bottom sheet does not have a default dim feature.

You can use `ModalBottomSheetLayout`, or `BottomDrawer` to have that effect. But neither these layout have peek height, only expand states.

```
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        sheetElevation = 8.dp,
        sheetContent = {
            SheetContent()
        }
    ) {
        MainContent(modalBottomSheetState)
    }
```

Or

```
    val drawerState = rememberBottomDrawerState(BottomDrawerValue.Closed)

    BottomDrawer(
        gesturesEnabled = gesturesEnabled,
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {

        },
        content = {
   
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside your `sheetContent` block just add:

```kotlin
sheetContent = {
    val isDimVisible by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.targetValue == SheetValue.Expanded
        }
    }
    if (isDimVisible) {
        Box(
          modifier = Modifier
             .fillMaxSize()
             .zIndex(1f)
             .background(color = BottomSheetDefaults.ScrimColor)
           )
    }
    //Rest of the content
}
```

Comment: sheetContent is everything inside of the bottom sheet. This will just add a non transparent grey box above the content.